# How to put a weapon in a display case?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

How do I put my weapon in my display case? It only shows the `E` key for open display case and close display case. Below is a screen shot. Also can a bow fit in a display case?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To put your weapon in a display case, you'll have to drop your weapon from your inventory and physically maneuver it into the case (I think holding the 'Z' key is what you do here).

Comment: Some mods add functionality that adds your current weapon to the display case (like with the weapon plaques on the walls). Not sure if this also a base functionality for homes in the vanilla game.

Comment: @Ids That functionality for weapon plaques is vanilla, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Drop your weapon into the case, and hold your button you normally use to pick thins up while hovering over the weapon to drag it into the case better. After closing the case, press the "~" key, click on the case, and type "lock (some number)" (without quotes) to lock it. The number you put is the lock level.